# When i want to make object null in java spring frame work

Tags: java, spring-mvc

A)

```
private AccmasService accmasService;

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "accmasService")
public void setAccmasService(AccmasService accmasService) {
    this.accmasService = accmasService;
}
```

If we need to release service object? why?

B)

> Global object

```
  private String obj=null ;
    private String data = null;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/acchead", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accHead(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       //code
        obj=null;
        data=null;
// Whant to make this object null

        return "acc_mas";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/accmas/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addService(@ModelAttribute("accmas") Accmas ac, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,HttpServletRequest request) {
        ac.setLoginCode((String) request.getSession().getAttribute("emplyeeCode"));
        if (ac.getAccCode().equals("0")) {
           //code
        } else {
           //code
        }

        if(ac.getAccCode().equals("0")){
            obj=null;
        }else{
            obj = ac.getAccCode();
        }
        data = "save";
        ac=null;// need to make null nor not
        return "redirect:/acchead";
    }
```

1. We want to make all object null like data, obj also object for the
   model class?
2. When will the model class object release?
3. If there any other method for garbage collection?

Comment: Why do you want to release your service object?

Comment: I am asking about that i need to release  that object?

Comment: `Whant to make this object null` which object?

Comment: obj , data, also i am create object ac for the model class

Comment: I've read this question four times and I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: thank you mikeTheLiar,  this program i am using object (obj,data) that are declared as global object , after using it making  there value is null ,is a good approach? while    doing  this any benefits in the garbage collection and efficiency of the program?